# Looking for a way to call Perl XS C API functions/macros from helper functions

Tags: c, perl, xs

I’ve been experimenting with the Perl XS C API and have hit a roadblock.

I have simplified my example below. Assuming an existing struct MyObject then to access property “a” or “b” and create a hash for either one I could use the following code:

```
typedef struct {
   const char *prop_a;
   const char *prop_b;
   struct {
    const char **items;
    int num;
   } names;
}   MyObjectInfo;

typedef MyObjectInfo *MyObject;

MODULE = my_obj            PACKAGE = MyObject    PREFIX = my_obj_

SV *
my_obj_a(o)
   MyObject o

   CODE:
   SV *info = newHV();
   hv_store(info, “a”, 1, newSVpvn(o->prop_a, strlen(o->prop_a)), 0);
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < o->names.num; i++) {
        const char *n = o->names.items[i];
        hv_store(info, n, strlen(n), newSViv(i), 0);
   }
   RETVAL = sv_2mortal(newrv_noinc(val));
 
   OUTPUT:
   RETVAL

SV *
my_obj_b(o)
   MyObject o

   CODE:
   SV *info = newHV();
   hv_store(info, “b”, 1, newSVpvn(o->prop_b, strlen(o->prop_b)), 0);
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < o->names.num; i++) {
        const char *n = o->names.items[i];
        hv_store(info, n, strlen(n), newSViv(i), 0);
   }
   RETVAL = sv_2mortal(newrv_noinc(val));
 
   OUTPUT:
   RETVAL
```

What I want to do is share some of the functionality in a utility function like this

```
SV *create_obj_hash(MyObjectInfo *o, const char *k, const char *p) {
    SV *val = newHV();
    hv_store(val, k, strlen(k), newSVpvn(p, strlen(p)), 0);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < o->names.num; i++) {
        const char *n = o->names.items[i];
        hv_store(info, n, strlen(n), newSViv(i), 0);
    }
    return val;
}

MODULE = my_obj            PACKAGE = MyObject    PREFIX = my_obj_

SV *
my_obj_a(o)
   MyObject o

   CODE:
   SV *info = create_obj_hash(o, “a”, o->prop_a);
   RETVAL = sv_2mortal(newrv_noinc(val));
 
   OUTPUT:
   RETVAL

SV *
my_obj_b(o)
   MyObject o

   CODE:
   SV *info = create_obj_hash(o, “b”, o->prop_b);;
   RETVAL = sv_2mortal(newrv_noinc(val));
 
   OUTPUT:
   RETVAL
```

But, when I do the macro expansion within create_obj_hash() fails with the following messages.

```
myobj.xs: In function 'create_obj_hash':
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE/perl.h:175:16: error: 'my_perl' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'my_fork'?
 #  define aTHX my_perl
                ^~~~~~~
ppport.h:6145:41: note: in definition of macro 'MUTABLE_PTR'
 #  define MUTABLE_PTR(p) ({ void *_p = (p); _p; })
                                         ^
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE/hv.h:651:17: note: in expansion of macro 'MUTABLE_HV'
 #define newHV() MUTABLE_HV(newSV_type(SVt_PVHV))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE/perl.h:188:18: note: in expansion of macro 'aTHX'
 #  define aTHX_  aTHX,
                  ^~~~
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE/embed.h:532:40: note: in expansion of macro 'aTHX_'
 #define newSV_type(a)  Perl_newSV_type(aTHX_ a)
                                        ^~~~~
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE/hv.h:651:28: note: in expansion of macro 'newSV_type'
 #define newHV() MUTABLE_HV(newSV_type(SVt_PVHV))
                            ^~~~~~~~~~
myobj.xs:42:19: note: in expansion of macro 'newHV'
     return (void*)newHV();
```

Thank you very much in advance,
Brian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [perl xs module writing - Use another function from within same xs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569264/perl-xs-module-writing-use-another-function-from-within-same-xs-file)

Comment: Specifically the [answer mentioning `pTHX_` and `aTHX_`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569810) should help you.

Comment: Thank you @nwellnhof, that was exactly the trick/hint I needed. Adding the pTHX and aTHX macro inclusions made it all just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might be missing some or all of the following:

```c
#define PERL_NO_GET_CONTEXT
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"
```

---

The main issue is that you aren't providing the *context* to the API calls.

Some builds of Perl allow processes to have multiple instances of the interpreter running at once. If `-Dmultiplicity` was used when Perl was created, the build will support this. (You can check this using `perl -V:usemultiplicity`.) `-Dmultiplicity` is implied by `-Dusethreads`, the option to build a `perl` with thread support (since an instance of the interpreter is created for each thread).

As such, a large number of Perl API calls require the caller to provide a *context* ("THX") which identifies the interpreter to use. Think of the interpreter as an object (in the OOP sense of the word), and the context as the invocant.

In XS code, a variable containing the context is automatically created for you. This variable is automatically passed to Perl API call through the use of macros.

```c
#define newSVpvn(a,b) Perl_newSVpvn(aTHX_ a,b)
//                                  ^^^^^
//                      Causes the context to be passed
//                      to Perl_newSVpvn, the real name
//                      of newSVpvn.
```

As such, you'll need the context to make this work (no matter which of `newSVpvn` and `Perl_newSVpvn` you use). To obtain the context, use the following macros:

- If your function has no parameters besides the context,

  - Use `pTHX` as the first parameter of your function declaration.
  - Use `aTHX` as the first argument in calls to your function.
- If your function has parameters besides the context,

  - Use `pTHX_` as the first parameter of your function declaration.
  - Use `aTHX_` as the first argument in calls to your function.

"`p`" stands for "parameter", "`a`" stands for "argument", and "`_`" represents a comma.

In your case, you'd use

```c
STATIC SV *create_obj_hash(pTHX_ MyObjectInfo *o, const char *k, const char *p) {
#define create_obj_hash(a,b,c) create_obj_hash(aTHX_ a,b,c)
    ...
}
```

Thanks to the `#define`, you can continue using

```c
SV *info = create_obj_hash(o, "b", o->prop_b);
```

---

Untested. Let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Thank you, all those headers are there - the key to the whole thing (as you explained) was the missing aTHX and pTHX macro inclusions. Once I added those it all worked.